# .NET API Can't Find Data I Want

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to save two variables out of a json request but i'm just trying to get the first one working this is my request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key=KEY&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&items=1&item0=http://www.majestic.com&datasource=fresh");
  {
     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
     using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
          JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
          JToken Trusty = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][2];
          var newdomain = new Identifier { domain = model.domain, contact = model.contact, contactname = model.contactname, price = model.price, type = model.type, TrustFlow = Int32.Parse(Trusty.ToString()), CitationFlow = 65, RI = model.RI, MJTopicsID = model.MJTopicsID, UserTableID = model.UserTableID };
          ViewBag.newdomain = newdomain;
          db.Identifiers.Add(newdomain);
```

This returns this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

I've also tried

```
Token Trusty = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"]["TrustFlow"][0];
```

this returns:

> 'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "TrustFlow". Int32 array index expected.'

This is the json I tried separating it myself as on the url it just came as one long line:

```
{
"Code":"OK","ErrorMessage":"","FullError":"","FirstBackLinkDate":"2017-08-17","IndexBuildDate":"2017-11-20 10:51:56","IndexType":1,"MostRecentBackLinkDate":"2017-11-18","QueriedRootDomains":0,"QueriedSubDomains":0,"QueriedURLs":1,"QueriedURLsMayExist":0,"ServerBuild":"2017-10-25 14:33:44","ServerName":"QUACKYO","ServerVersion":"1.0.6507.24412","UniqueIndexID":"20171120105156-FRESH",
"DataTables":{
    "Results":{
         "Headers":{
"MaxTopicsRootDomain":30,"MaxTopicsSubDomain":20,"MaxTopicsURL":10,"TopicsCount":3
    },
         "Data":[{
"RefDomainTypeProtocolHTTPS":"228","CitationFlow":42,"TrustFlow":29,"TrustMetric":29,"TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_0":"Health/Animal","TopicalTrustFlow_Value_0":26,"TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_1":"Business","TopicalTrustFlow_Value_1":25,"TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_2":"Computers/Internet/Domain Names","TopicalTrustFlow_Value_2":24
    }
]}}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your "Data" array only has one element in it, and you are asking for the third with [2].  The other thing you tried is asking for the first element of the Trustflow array, but Trustflow isn't an array.  Drop the [0] on your second attempt?

Comment: Arrays are 0 index based. So you will access the first item as `someArray[0]`

Comment: @MarcTalbot it returns the same error 'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "TrustFlow". Int32 array index expected.' sorry I meant to say when I said it returns at Int32 it returns it at the previous level, I will edit

Comment: @Shyju I see so would data be an array, so would it be Data[2] ?

Comment: @Shyju ah I see it opens an array on the data section with [] how would that be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Data` property is an array of size 1. Arrays are 0 index based. So you will access the first item as `someArray[0]` and second item as `someArray[1]` and so on

To read the `int` value stored inside the `TrustFlow` property of the first item in the Data array, you can do this

```
int trustFlow = jObject["DataTables"]["Results"]["Data"][0]["TrustFlow"].Value<int>();
```

This should work for the JSON Data you provided in the question. Keep in mind that this code expects the data  to be in that structure . For example, if your `Data` array does not have any item, or your `Results` does not have a `Data` property, the code will crash ( probably with a null reference exception). You can add the null check yourself before trying to access the value as needed.

Comment: works a dream!!! thank you! haven't had any experience with arrays quite yet but really clears it up for me as well as makes it work :) Thanks!